# javascript regex to extract {abc} but not '{abc}'

Tags: javascript, regex

As regex newbie, I want to extract {abc} but not '{abc}' from

```
test1 '{abc}' test2 {abc}
```

I tried https://regex101.com/r/6egYRc/1

```
/[^']{abc}[^']/g
```

but it doesn't work : seems I don't understand [^']

Comment: I think you want to use lookarounds `(?<!'){abc}(?!')` https://regex101.com/r/6TjaLm/1 This part `[^']` expects a single character to be present.

Comment: oh my thanks why is it so complicated :)

Comment: For more info on lookarounds and character classes see https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html